# Conversion of String to DateTime : Android

Tags: android, sqlite, datetime

I have a field (named as time, but type is TEXT) in my Sqlite Database. In current format of that column is `YYYY:MM:DD_HH:MM` (as 2011:11:01_11:30 ). Now I have to sort this column, so I think I have to do two things:

1. Convert string value to date.
2. Then sort with column.

Then how can I convert that column into DateTime? Or is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To convert String into Date, In my case this works fine,

```
String startTime = "2011-09-05 15:00:23";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"); 
Date date1 = dateFormat.parse(startTime);
```

**EDIT:**

> For Date and Time in SQLite

**1.2 Date and Time Datatype**

SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates and/or times. Instead, the built-in [Date And Time Functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) of SQLite are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER values:

```
* TEXT as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").
* REAL as Julian day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian calendar.
* INTEGER as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC.
```

Applications can chose to store dates and times in any of these formats and freely convert between formats using the built-in date and time functions.

**So, just use as a INTEGER or TEXT and use ORDER BY clause for sorting.**

Comment: But I want to sort this field using query, then will it work? How can that be.

Comment: +1 Ok, I am going to use your logic, hope it will work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Its best practice to use long data type for  date-time value in-spite of text.

Then you can use it in ur code simply by calling Date class constructor to get ur Date and Time.

This makes ur sorting operation simply easy.