# How to Compare system date with mydate in android 2.1?

Tags: android, datetime, date, android-date

in my Android application, i am taking  date and time from database. but i am not able to get the date in the "Date" Format from the database into my application, the date is in string format, so i am not able to compare the system date to database date.
if i convert the system date into string then i am not able to update the date into the database in recurring case. i also want to update the database date if the system date and database date is matched.

how can i achieve this is android.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: here I answered for how to convert string Date into Date object [Conversion of String to DateTime : Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7963042/conversion-of-string-to-datetime-android/7963067#7963067).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert String to Date like this:

```
String str = "12/12/1912";
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date date = formatter.parse(str);
```

And back to String

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
System.out.println("Date is : " + formatter.format(date));
```

And [Date](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) has [before](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#before%28java.util.Date%29) and [after](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#after%28java.util.Date%29) methods and can be [compared to each other](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo%28java.util.Date%29).

By the way there is also a library called  [Joda](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/), you can also check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println("Current time => " + c.getTime());
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM");
    formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
```

Comment: Better stick to Caner's answer. You're **kind of** right, but you might want to extend your answer beyond this specific non-popular format. Format of `dd-MMMM` seems weird - you ignore the *year* component of the date string and expect *month* component to be full month name? (`MMMM`)

Comment: you're missing the essence - OP's trying to *compare* two dates. You're proposition doesn't cover comparison, only conversion from *Date* to *String*.