# Compare two datetime in Android

Tags: java, android, datetime

I want to compare date1(2013/1/21 21:22:30) with date2(now) in one method

I want to get how much date,hours,minutes and second Remaining form Date 1

```
String mDate,mHour,mMinute,mSecond;

DateComparedateTime(String Date1)
{
 // compare  Date1 with now 
   mDate = Difference date with Date1 and Now;
   mHour = Difference hour with Date1 and Now;
   mMinute = Difference minute with Date1 and Now;
   mSecond = Difference second with Date1 and Now;
}
```

how can create this method ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8135689/how-to-compare-system-date-with-mydate-in-android-2-1

Comment: What do you want to compare, what the difference is between the dates, or which one comes first?

Comment: I want to get how much date,hours,minutes and second Remaining form Date 1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
      SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");


    String dateNow = sdf.format(currentDate.getTime());
      Date today =  new Date(dateNow);
      Date finalDay = null;
      finalDay = (Date) sdf.parse("MM/dd/yyyy");
    int numberOfDays=(int)((finalDay.getTime()-today.getTime())/(3600*24*1000));
```

Comment: how can get numberOfHours and numberOfMinuts and NumberOfSecond?

Comment: 'int numberOfDays=(int)((finalDay.getTime()-today.getTime())/(1000));' will give you the number of seconds . int numberOfDays='(int)((finalDay.getTime()-today.getTime())/(3600*1000));' will give you number of hours ..

Comment: I have a Date with string type and want to compare now

Answer (score 5):

you can use [Date.compareTo()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo%28java.util.Date%29) method.

```
DateComparedateTime(String date1)
{
    System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss").format(date1).compareTo(new Date()))
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

this might help you...follow it carefully..

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
System.out.println("calender time in millies" + c.getTimeInMillis());
System.out.println("calender time in millies" + c.getTime());
long diffInSec = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(c.getTimeInMillis());
System.out.println("time in seconds :: " + diffInSec);
```