# Convert string to a DateTime to sort in SQLite

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, datetime

I have a string value for date stored in my database in the format: DD/MM/YY HH:MM:SS and would like to order by this date and time.

I am working on an android app with SQLite, is this possible?

**EDIT :**
I would like to convert and compare within the SQLite statement.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7963042/conversion-of-string-to-datetime-android go for it

Comment: FYI, looks like you're getting downvoted because this is a problem that does not need solving and/or was easily answerable elsewhere. Datetime strings are already formatted in such a way that you can just sort them while in string format. Use `ORDER BY my_date` clause to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach add new integer column and update database to store date in numeric format.

1. Select id, date_str from table where date_long is null
2. For each row update table set date_long = DateFormat.parse(date_str) where _id = ?

Answer (score -1):

you can use Order by clause try this:

```
Cursor cursor = db.query(tableName, null, columnName + "=?",
            new String[]{argValue}, null, null, Constants._DATE_TIME + " DESC");
```